# Understanding a contradiction regarding least upper bounds

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm reading [a proof of the IVT](http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/IntValueTheorem13.htm) and a particular contradiction regarding least upper bounds seems a bit unclear (to me).  Firstly, we have $S = \{ x \in [a,b] \mid f(x) \le 0 \}$.

Now, we know that this set is nonempty and bounded, thus, by the Completeness Axiom, it must have a least upper bound, name it $c$. Now, we want to disprove that $f(c)>0$ and the writer attempts to do this by contradiction. Essentially, he goes on to deduce that if $f(c)>0$ then $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ in the interval $c - \delta < x < c + \delta$, and from this he goes on to deduce the following:

> But $c$ was the least upper bound of the set $S$ which produced non-positive values of $f(x)$, yet it would appear that we found a smaller upper bound, $c - \delta _1$. This is impossible, and therefore $f(c) > 0$ is impossible.

However, I fail to follow why $c-\delta$ is also a least upper bound, for, from the above conclusions, it seems that $f(c-\delta)\le0$, implying that $c-\delta$ is within $S$ and thus that $c$ is still the least upper bound of $S$.

(Note: Continuity of $f$ was assumed)

Comment: Continuity of $f$ must have been assumed, but you didn't tell us that. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Neither @MichaelHardy, nor me are editing your post for the pleasure of doing it, so leave our changes as they are, please.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I added that in.

Comment: @AlexM. I only added the continuity of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c\geq x$ for all $x$ with $f(x)\leq 0$, and if $f(x)>0$ for $x\in (c-\delta_1,c)$, so that no $x$ in the interval belongs to the set of $x$ indicated, then in fact $c-\delta_1\geq x$ for all $x$ with $f(x)\leq 0$.  This shows that the least upper bound of such $x$ is $\leq c-\delta_1$.  This contradicts our assumption that least upper bound equals $c$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)\geq0$ if $x\geq c$ because $c$ is an upper bound.
$f(x)\geq0$ if $c-\delta<x<c$ because $f(c)>0$.
So $f(x)\geq0$ if $c-\delta<x$.
So $c-\delta$ is also an upper bound for $S$.
$c-\delta<c$, so $c$ is not the *least* upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in $(c-\delta_1,c+\delta_1)$, you have that any element of $(c-\delta_1,c)$ is an upper bound of $S$. Hence $c$ can't be the least upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

These are my thoughts on the matter:

If the least upper bound $c$ is an element of $S$ then you know that $f(c)\leq 0\ ,$ which is want you want.

Otherwise, $c$ is **not** an element of $S\ .$ However, $c$ *is* an element of $\text{Dom}(f) = [a,b].$ Pick a sequence of rational numbers of $\text{Dom}(f)$ converging to $c\ ,$ $r_{n} \to c\ .$ Since function $f$ is continuous you know that $f(r_{n})$ can be made to be as close to $f(c)$ as you like if you make sure that $r_{n}$ is sufficiently close to $c\ .$

Suppose that $f(c) = \varepsilon\ ,$ for some $\varepsilon > 0\ .$ By choosing $r_{n}$ sufficiently close to $c$ you can make $f(r_{n})$ lie $(0.5\varepsilon)$-close to $f(c)\ .$ For such rational numbers $f(r_{n})>0\ ,$ which is a contradiction.

Consequently, no matter the location of the least upper bound $c$ it is always the case that $f(c)\leq 0\ .$